# JS - Property of object with assigned value becomes undefined

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I am trying to run this code in js

```
    function platform() {
       platform.list.push(this);
       //some more code
    }
    platform.lf = false;
```

and I have all instances of platforms stored on platform.list. But when I try to this:

```
    console.log(platform.list[0].lf);
```

I get undefined? Any help? (I do have one instance of the platform object)

Comment: @BorisLipschitz, if that's a constructor with a `list` property which is an Array, that would be alright, but I'm guessing OP doesn't have a `list` property, and that's not a constructor, otherwise OP would use `this.list.push` instead. Then again... who knows. Not enough code to answer the question. Oh, @CroquetFlamingo, platform is just a function, not an Object. If it is a constructor need to call `new platform` to create an Object. Also, you should uppercase your first character of your constructors by convention.

Comment: @StackSlave since my first comment is rather dumb (didn't read the OP properly) and since the most likely answer is that he just doesn't realize "platform.lf" and "this.lf" aren't the same thing, i am deleting my previous comments :-)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do? How comes it seems to work fine on the snippet? Did you forget to init lf (this.lf = ...) inside your "//some more code" part, one you didn't post?

Just a side note - the platfrom.lf, and the lf that belongs to the class instances, one you are trying to access, are totally different things.

```js
test.list = []

function test()
{
  test.list.push(this);
  this.x = Math.random();
}

a = new test();
b = new test();

console.log(test.list.length);
console.log(test.list[0].x);
console.log(test.list[1].x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is probably what you need to learn. If you are creating a constructor *(which I now recommend instead of class due to private variable reasons)*, it is not an Object until you call `new` on it.

```js
function Platform(){
  const a = ['lame', 1, 'test']; // private array
  this.lf = true;
  this.testFunc = ()=>{
    // no arguments array in an arrow function
    console.log(a);
    return this; // for property chaining
  }
}
function Platforms(){
  this.list = [];
  this.addPlatform = function(){
    this.list.push(...arguments);
    return this;
  }
}
const pf = new Platforms, np = new Platform;
np.lf = false;
pf.addPlatform(new Platform, new Platform, np);
pf.list[0].lf = false;
console.log(pf.list); np.testFunc();
```

You may also like to see this design:

```js
function Platform(){
  this.lf = true;
}
function Platforms(){
  this.list = [];
  this.addPlatform = function(){
    this.list.push(new Platform);
    return this;
  }
}
const pf = new Platforms;
pf.addPlatform().addPlatform().addPlatform();
pf.list[0].lf = false;
console.log(pf.list);
```